How to separate express app routes into different source files in Cloud Functions?
I am currently developing an API with google's Cloud function, and wanted to know how arrange my Node.js index.ts file so that I can keep my callback functions in separated files while still handling them as POST and "merging" them at a single file using Node.js routing. I tried to follow the examples in this question and the official documentation, but they all implement the callbacks in the main index.ts file, which obviously isn't the best approach.
My function file helloWorld.ts:
export type Indexable = { [key: string ]: any};

import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send(`<h1>${request.params[0]}</h1>`);
});

index.ts:
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import express = require("express");
import {helloWorld} from "./helloWorld";

const app = express();

app.get("hello", (req, res) => helloWorld(req, res));

exports.events = onRequest(app);


Don't use onRequest in your helloWorld.ts.  Just define and export the function that accepts request and response, then import it and use it in your express route in index.ts.

This could be closed as duplicate of this thread and its comments, but I'll only flag it as such after confirmation that this works for you.

Thanks it works now. I was also missing an escape before "/hello" route. Another question if it is permitted. How can type my req and res params in my helloWorld.ts file instead of  placing Request<{     name: string; }, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> on every file?

@LevonT.C. You could create a central custom-types.ts file and add an alias for it there. e.g. export type MyAppRouteHandler = (req: Request<{ name: string; }, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response) => void. Then in each file, use import type { MyAppRouteHandler } from "./custom-types.ts" and use it with export const handler: MyAppRouteHandler = (req, res) => { ... }; export default handler;. This was a freebie, in future, its best practice to ask on a separate question.
